# Pusher Websocket not connecting after migration to Swift 2

Tags: websocket, swift2, pusher

I am using Starscream and Pusher-swift in an app I've made about a month ago with Xcode 6, all was working fine, Pusher connected and was able to receive messages.

After Xcode updated itself to 7 because I forgot to turn off the computer, and after I spent a week sorting out about 19375891237849 errors, now I'm stuck at the Websocket part of the application which simply doesn't want to connect.

No errors are thrown. Pusher thinks it's connected (PusherConnection.connected is set to true) but it can't subscribe to any channel and no errors pop up.

I am looking at the Starscream code, can't seem to manage to figure out what's going on.

Has anyone seen this happening with Xcode 7?

Is there maybe a setting (like for instance that NSAllowsArbitraryLoads setting to allow loading objects via HTTP) that blocks websockets by default? (not that I can imagine why would Apple do such a thing, maybe they started hiring developers from Microsoft or something).

Comment: Thanks Eric. Only mentioned the Xcode tag as it might also be something related to Xcode settings or the simulator.

Comment: Found the problem, it actually lies within Pusher-swift, function handleConnectionEstablishedEvent, tries to extract a socket_id from a JSON object casted to String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within PusherSwift:

```
private func handleConnectionEstablishedEvent(json: PusherEventJSON) {
    if let data = json["data"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        if let socketId = data["socket_id"] as? String {
        //if let connectionData = getPusherEventJSONFromString(data), socketId = connectionData["socket_id"] as? String { // this will fail silently. 
            self.connected = true
            self.socketId = socketId

            for (_, channel) in self.channels.channels {
                if !channel.subscribed {
                    if !self.authorize(channel) {
                        print("Unable to subscribe to channel: \(channel.name)")
                    } else {
                        print("Subscribed to \(channel.name)")
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("No connection data 2")
        }
    } else {
        print("No connection data 1")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Nick, please could you write this up as an issue on the repo?

Also, I've just tested locally and it seems to be working fine for me. Any more details that you can provide on what sort of channel you're subscribing to etc?

Comment: Hi and thanks for all your work on Pusher-swift! The issue above was not related to a particular channel but the connection to the WS server. I don't have access to my GH account right now, but if you could replace the line I've commented out with the one right above it should be fine.

Comment: Hey Nick, I'm not sure what that helps achieve? The socketId is part of the data fiel, which is a JSON-encoded hash and so that needs to be parsed in order to retrieve the socketId. You can find more information about the Pusher protocol here: https://pusher.com/docs/pusher_protocol#connection-events

Comment: Without the socket_id getting parsed correctly it thinks it's not connected, so it won't subscribe to any channels or receive any events.

Comment: Could you possibly create a gist / sample app that isn't working for you and I'll take a look at that?